# Why does Mathematica just return Hold of my Input?

Tags: equation-solving, error-tracking

Example:

```
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]

Output: Hold[Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]]
```

What is the problem?
Any child can solve this in its head

Comment: For me it works. Have you tried stopping the kernel prior to this?

Comment: I don't know how but restarting Mathematica solved the problem... Still curious why this happened

Comment: You must have assigned some value to `x` that causes the code to loop. Just like what happens when you assign `x = x + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]
```

gives the correct answer. Unless x or a are defined.
It is pretty much guaranteed to return the correct answer if you Clear the symbols prior to execution or use a Block.

```
x = 1 
a = 1
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]
```

does not work, even if only x is defined. This is actually fairly confusing and might be because the expression does not get properly Hold 'ed. Be Aware!

```
x = 1 
a = 1
Clear[a,x]
Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]
```

does

```
x = 1 
a = 1
Block[{a, x},
 Solve[x^2 + a x + 1 == 0, x]]
{x, a}
```

does aswell while preserving any potential values of both x and a